# Check in JS if an Array contains an object with the same attributs value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, contains

I'm looking for a method which will generically checks if an Array contains an object with the exact same param values.

Not something specific, a generic implementation.

Exemple :

```
var obj1 = {name : 'name1', id : 1, value : 'value1'};
var obj2 = {name : 'name2', id : 2};
var obj3 = {name : 'name3', id : 3, value : 'value1', title : 'title3'};
var obj4 = {name : 'name4', id : 4, value : 'value1', title : null};

var arrayObj = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];

var test1 = {name : 'name1', id : 1}; // One missing attribut
var test2 = {name : 'name2', id : 2, value : 'value2'}; // One additional attribut
var test3 = {name : 'name3', id : 3, value : 'value1', title : 'title33'}; // attribut with different value
var test4 = {name : 'name4', id : 4, value : 'value1'}; // same attributs beside the null one
var test5 = {name : 'name3', id : 3, value : 'value1', titleBis : 'title3'}; // attributs with different names
var test6 = {value : 'value1', id : 1, name : 'name1'}; // same attributs and attributs value but in different order

containsMethod(arrayObj, test1); // false
containsMethod(arrayObj, test2); // false
containsMethod(arrayObj, test3); // false
containsMethod(arrayObj, test4); // true
containsMethod(arrayObj, test5); // false
containsMethod(arrayObj, test6); // true
containsMethod(arrayObj, obj2); // true
```

Please let me know in comment if it's not clear.
I've seen a lot of question for specific object, here I'm looking for a generic version.

Ideally this would also work for String, number etc, not only object with attributs

Comment: You forgot to post `containsMethod` code

Comment: That's what he is looking for  think.

Comment: Couldn't you just compare ids of each object ?

Comment: I would choose [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35821859/4571082) (from the duplicate question) and would combine it with a simple loop over the objects in the `arrayObj` array.

Comment: It's easy to implement with just a filter() array method --> 4 lines of code